# Android and data visualization : How to present data in a better way?

Tags: android, list, twitter, visualization

I want to present my data in a better way (instead of a simple list). Is it in Android possible to present a list with data (for example tweet-messages) in a special way like this:

[image]

Any other kind of visualization is also welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data representation in your linked example is not necessarily "better", just different.  In the case of a mobile device, that particular visualization might actually be worse, given the small size of the screen.

To do something like that, you would have to draw everything yourself (which is not necessarily "a bad thing", just different).

Comment: Yes, maybe it is not really "better" like a list. But I want to try to present data in such this way like the example. I know that this kind of visualization is too large, but isn't it possible for the user to touch and drag it on the small screen?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Here is a link to get you started with your own 2D graphics: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: Thank you! Do you know If there is a tool in Android where you can present the data like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOGmnnGpoqg (min 00:57 )

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I don't think there's anything built into Android itself to do that. There may be third-party controls available, but you'd have more fun writing that kind of stuff yourself.

Comment: Too bad :S Do you know If there are any other good third party libraries for UI or to present data in an other way than lists?

Comment: Yes: it's a library named "honeyriver". Learn how to draw stuff yourself, and you won't ever regret it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do ListView and any variations of that.

GridView or anything that lists things horizontally and vertically

Or you can use the SDK to draw your own.

You should share what you are trying to represent so we can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, actually I want to present the data in a way like this, but It shouldn't be so complicated like this one: http://bit.ly/gWpAYJ (the circles are the users and the squares are the messages of each user)